# Scenekit allowsCameraControl and cameraNode use together

Tags: ios, scenekit

Is there any way to use both `allowsCameraControl` set to YES and set `cameraNode` transform or orientation?

I have been trying setting allowsCameraControl to YES, then use CMMotionManger to control `cameraNode`(same SCNView). The result is, when i start tap and slip(start using `allowsCameraControl`), the change of `cameraNode` is not happening after that(only finger slip will change the fill of view).